# Saving a file in code - Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows

I want to serialize some information I retrieve from the user in a small .NET 3.5 WinForms app
to an XML file saved locally on his computer. Currently all the stations of the users intended
to use this app have Windows 7 on them.

The thing is that the system won't just let me save the file anywhere, and I need
a place that is both accessible through code (the system will allow saving there),
and preferably is generic enough so that if tomorrow I want to run this app on a different version of Windows this path will still exist.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: See [Isolated Storage (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Do you have a deployment project? if you do, create a "data" folder into the application folder and save your data or files there. (would be the bin folder during development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write to the local *Application Data* folder.

You can access it from C# as the `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` folder.

Another option would be `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have .net give the User's Userpath. Like "C:\Users\User\MyDocuments".
Actually, that's what George's link is about. +1 for him.